# Selenium waitFor and confirm combinations

Tags: php, unit-testing, selenium, phpunit, selenium-ide

I am running Selenium on a page showing a list of objects and a 'delete' link for each object.

Whenever the user clicks on the **delete** link, a *confirm dialog* shows and asks for confirmation. If the user clicks OK, then the object is deleted and the page reloads.

Now, I want to test this behavior with **PHPUnit** and **Selenium**.

The following code is what I eventually tried :

```
$this->open('account/admin');
$this->assertElementPresent('css=h1');
[...]
$this->verifyElementPresent('css=td.button-column a.delete[href$="delete/1"]');
$this->click('css=td.button-column a.delete[href$="delete/1"]');
$this->assertConfirmation('*supprimer*'); (1)
// $this->waitForPageToLoad(); (2)
$this->waitForElementNotPresent('css=td.button-column a.delete[href$="delete/1"]'); (3)
```

I am pretty sure the test should succeed because manuel testing of the feature is OK. Also, I have disabled the login protection for this page : any user can reach it.

Unfortunately, I can't achieve to test if the page has reloaded : the test **(3)** always fails on "WaitFor time out"...

After my understanding of the documentation, the problem from a Selenese point of view is that the action which causes the *reload* of the page is **click()** but the reload will actually take place *after* the confirm pop up dialog has returned true. And *waitForXXX()* commands should be launched immediately after the action which causes the reload.

I tried to comment **(1)** although the [Selenium documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#alerts-popups-and-multiple-windows) says that pop up dialogs must be handled with their related *assertXXX(*). the results are the same.

I also tried to *waitForPageToLoad()* at **(2)** but this one just... waits (300000000 milliseconds, default value obviously and that's enough for any page to reload...)

I'm stuck and unable to figure how I could test this simple and rather mundane behavior...
What am I missing ?

Comment: I am assuming that you have a list of elements that need to be deleted. So each time you delete the first one and the page reloads, the second one NOW becomes the first one. So when you are `waitForElementNotPresent`the element is actually present (so you are checking for the wrong condition). How about you assert that the length of the delete column gets reduced with each consecutive click on the delete link?

Comment: @amey You're right, I have a list of elements to delete. But I guess the element I look for is not present after the click : the selector includes an id *(delete/1)*, thus this selector must not find the element after deletion.

Comment: the element is being found, hence its failing. So you have two ways to handle it, find that element it is searching and work aroud that or check for another condition. I would chose the latter.

Comment: @amey Sorry but I don't understand what you are trying to tell me. The element is found but it shall not be found after the page has reloaded, right ?